# JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource jsp

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, jsp, websphere

When external service call our spring controller method "/resource/access", error showing in browser as "**JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /WEB-INF/jsp/resource/access.jsp**" rarely. I investigate by searching this error in websites, but i could not the exact root casue. I don't know this error caused by us / IBM / external web service.

Please let me know the root cause of this error if anybody knows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/resource/access",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String access(@PathVariable("path") String path, HttpServletRequest httpRequest,HttpSession session){
    return "portal/txn";
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

> [12/6/18 11:35:38:712 MYT] 000002c4 ServletWrappe E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E:
>   Uncaught service() exception root cause dispatcher:
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPErrorReport: JSPG0036E: Failed to
>   find resource /WEB-INF/jsp/resource/access.jsp    at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.findWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:447)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.getServletWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:338)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1010)

Answer (score 1):

You've hit something not allowed by spec.  "As per J2EE specification, JSP files should reside under web module root or under sub directory other than META-INF and WEB-INF."

This, and other reasons to get a JSPG0036E error, are explained in this link:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21282614